# Flex wrap in HTML on multiple span elements

Tags: html, word-wrap

For a website I have to display a div with multiple spans inside. Each one contains one character (with a specific colour class). When I use wraps of any kind, they don't recognize the text as whole and wrap on whitespace but rather on single characters (since it is for the computer only one input, that just fits this place)

See image:
[image: Image for clarification]

It should wrap at "Dieses Maß wird in [WRAP] Zoll angegeben.

```css
.colouredAnswer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.green {
  color: #008000;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="colouredAnswer">
  <span class="yellow-green">D</span>
  <span class="green">i</span>
  <span class="green">e</span>
  <span class="yellow">s</span>
  <span class="yellow-green">e</span>
  <span class="yellow-green">s</span>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <span class="green">M</span>
  <span class="green">a</span>
  <span class="green">ß</span>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <span class="green">w</span>
  <span class="green">i</span>
  <span class="green">r</span>
  <span class="yellow-green">d</span>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <span class="green">i</span>
  <span class="yellow-green">n</span>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <span class="green">Z</span>
  <span class="yellow-green">o</span>
  <span class="green">l</span>
  <span class="green">l</span>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <span class="green">a</span>
  <span class="green">n</span>
  <span class="green">g</span>
  <span class="green">e</span>
  <span class="green">g</span>
  <span class="green">e</span>
  <span class="green">b</span>
  <span class="green">e</span>
  <span class="green">n</span>
  <span class="green">.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the post and added example css of a colour class. There is no css for the "colouredAnswer"

Comment: Sure there is. You just had it inline, which is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping each word in a div:

```css
.colouredAnswer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.green {
  color: #008000;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="colouredAnswer">
  <div>
    <span class="yellow-green">D</span>
    <span class="green">i</span>
    <span class="green">e</span>
    <span class="yellow">s</span>
    <span class="yellow-green">e</span>
    <span class="yellow-green">s</span>
  </div>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <div>
    <span class="green">M</span>
    <span class="green">a</span>
    <span class="green">ß</span>
  </div>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <div>
    <span class="green">w</span>
    <span class="green">i</span>
    <span class="green">r</span>
    <span class="yellow-green">d</span></div>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <div>
    <span class="green">i</span>
    <span class="yellow-green">n</span>
  </div>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <div>
    <span class="green">Z</span>
    <span class="yellow-green">o</span>
    <span class="green">l</span>
    <span class="green">l</span></div>
  <span class="green"> </span>
  <div>
    <span class="green">a</span>
    <span class="green">n</span>
    <span class="green">g</span>
    <span class="green">e</span>
    <span class="green">g</span>
    <span class="green">e</span>
    <span class="green">b</span>
    <span class="green">e</span>
    <span class="green">n</span>
  </div>
  <span class="green">.</span>
</div>
```